# createElementNS is not properly working when https namespace is used

Tags: javascript, node.js, svg

I have below statement in one of the JS.

```
var path = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path')
```

This works well without minifying. After I execute the command `node r.js -o build.js` the same statement has become as below in minfied version.

```
var path = document.createElementNS('https://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path')
```

When I have http in the namespace I could able to see many svg properties, but after minifying there very less svg properties. Is there any way to solve this ?

**UPDATE:** As @Robert mentioned in the comment did below work around and worked.

```
var x='_'+'ttp'+'://...';
x=x.replace('_','h');
var path = document.createElementNS(x, 'path')
```

Comment: the only different I see is that it changed the protocol to `https` that shouldnt be your problem, probably is something else.

Comment: Yes, that's the difference and that gives me the problem

Comment: report that bug in your minifier to the support site for the minifier. That's not a URL in the namespace it's just a special string that has to be present exactly as-is. It just happens to look like a URL.

Comment: Presumably you could build up the namespace to fool the minifier var x = "h" + "ttp" + ":/"... then createElementNS(x, ...)

Comment: Thanks @RobertLongson, even this is changed to https while minifying. so tuned this workaround little bit as var x='_'+'ttp'+':/...' ; x=x.replace('_','h'); and worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Robert mentioned in the comment did below work around and worked.

```
var x='_'+'ttp'+'://...';
x=x.replace('_','h');
var path = document.createElementNS(x, 'path')
```